# How to remove a layout and add a new layout by button click

Tags: android, android-layout

i Want to remove a `relative layout` after a button click and add a new layout to the view .The relative layout is at `OnCreate()` and the button click is At `OnStart()`.

Comment: have you tried just hiding the layout?.. or setting the visibility to View.GONE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep both the layouts in your layout xml file. Keep the visibility of the second layout GONE. On button click, set the visibility of first layout as GONE and the visibility of second layout as VISIBLE.

you can use [setVisibility (int visibility)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method for this.